# How to await for StoreKit2 product load?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui, async-await, storekit2

how can I wait for the result of an async function that loads data for storekit2 in swiftui?

**Swift UI Code:**

```
struct SettingsForm : View {
    @State var selectedRegion: Int = 0
    @State var alwaysOriginalTitle: Bool = false
    @State
    private var products: [Product] = []
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    let productIds = ["premium"]
    init() {
          
       
        loadProducts()
      }
    private func loadProducts() async throws {
        self.products =  await Product.products(for: productIds)
        print(self.products)
    }
 ...
```

Comment: bro, have you resolved your problem? I got the same issue.

Comment: .....no @LauReal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to check if your products are loaded, and if not, show for example a `ProgressView`

```
struct SettingsForm : View {
    @State private var products: [Product]?
    let productIds = ["premium"]

    var body: some View {
        if let products {
            // Display list of products
        } else {
            ProgressView("Loading products")
                .task {
                    do {
                        try await loadProducts()
                    } catch {
                        // handleError
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    func loadProducts() async throws {
        self.products = try await Product.products(for: productIds)
    }
}
```

Comment: with your code i have this error: Myapp[4075:710731] [Default] [StoreKit] Did not receive any products or error for products request.

Comment: Have you set up your products in AppStoreConnect, or created a StoreKit configuration file?

Comment: i have create product and add storekit

Comment: And if you put `print(error)` in the `catch`, what do you see?

Comment: Did not receive any products or error for products request.